# Angular/Openlayers7.2.2: draw a polygon on a map

Tags: angular, openlayers, polygon

Could you please advise, what I am doing wrong. I can't compile the angular project with openLayers, geoJSON.

```
export class CGeometry {
  type: string;
  coordinates: Coordinate | Coordinate[]| Array<number>| number[][] | Coordinate[][][];
}
```

And I used it like:

```
result = new Feature(
          new MultiPolygon(
          (feature.geometry.coordinates as Array<Coordinate>[]).map((coord:) => {
            return transform(
              coord,
              'EPSG:4326',
              'EPSG:3857'
            )
          })));
```

I got an error:

> number[] | (Coordinate[][] | Polygon)[]"Argument of type "Coordinate[]" cannot be assigned to a parameter of type "number[] | (Coordinate[][] | Polygon)[]

Please advise how to fix

Comment: The coordinates for a MuliPolygon are `Array<Array<Array<Coordinate>>>` so `.map()` would not work with `ol/proj/transform` which takes a coordinate, but you can use the `transform` method of the geometry `new MultiPolygon(coordinates).transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857')`

Comment: Mike? thanks for your reply. Now, I fixed type of like:
```export class CGeometry {
  type: string;
  coordinates: Coordinate | Coordinate[] | Array<number> | number[][] | number[] | (Coordinate[][] | Polygon)[];
}```
And I got the same
`An argument of type "Coordinate | number[] | Coordinate[] | number[][] | (Coordinate[][] | Polygon)[]" cannot be assigned to a parameter of type "number[] | (Coordinate[][] | Polygon)[ ]".`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this work well

```
result = new Feature(
  new MultiPolygon(feature.geometry.coordinates as number[]).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).